# Ask for update to answers

Tags: discussion, answers

I got an error message, did a Google search for it, and found a Stack Overflow question about the exact message and situation. Unfortunately, it was asked in 2009 and the answers seem to be a little out of date, and don't quite fit my Windows 8.1, Eclipse Kepler configuration.

I would like to somehow re-ask the question to get new answers. What is the correct procedure?

If I knew the answer, it would be easy - I could post an additional answer to the old question. If I just post my question, it will be an obvious duplicate.

Comment: Post a comment and offer a bounty.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I'm trying that.

Comment: I don't know yet if @MatthewLundberg's suggestion will work, but it seems as though it should work as well as anything else, so I'm trying it and would accept it as an answer.

Comment: @Unihedron I'd expect an answer to contain more than just that one line that I have written in the comment.  Feel free to write one yourself.  Another path would be to look for a duplicate of this question that already has a great answer (one probably exists).  As for the OP, I wish the best of luck with getting the desired information.

Comment: Note that once you're offering a bounty, I view it as your responsibility to clean-up the question and make it generic.

Comment: "If I just post my question, it will be an obvious duplicate" - Obviously not as the answers that solved the "duplicate" do not solve your problem. It's hard to tell what to do in this specific situation without more details, but I feel it could be OK to re-ask the question as "Is there a solution _that works on my current platform_", linking to the old question and describing why the answers are not helping you. If applicable, you can then get a mod to merge the questions after getting an answer.

Comment: Yes, what @l4mpi said. :)

Comment: @l4mpi That seems a rather indirect way of achieving what I'm aiming for, a single question for the error message that has solutions for a range of environments, including my current environment.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan posting a bounty to an ages-old question with a note that you need a new solution is what seems "indirect" to me. You have a specific, on-topic issue which is not already answered on SO, go ask a question about it! That somebody else already asked a similar question _for a completely different environment_ does not matter at all here as your specific problem is still unanswered. If you had a programming question and found an old solution for a deprecated version of the language which doesn't work with your version, wouldn't you just ask a new question as well?

Comment: I thought that questions asking about updated versions are *not* be considered duplicates, especially if old answers don't work anymore. They would just be "related" at that point. Could've sworn I read that somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Post a comment and offer a bounty.

Comment: What if the user does not have enough rep to add a bounty?

Comment: +1 since I have done this in the past with great result.

Comment: @awalgarg earn enough reputaiton to add a bounty?

Comment: @Yakk eww. that joke is way old... It didn't even make me smile.

Comment: The first time I wanted to offer a bounty I did not have enough reputation. "earn enough reputation" seemed to me to be the obvious practical solution, not a joke. I spent a couple of days camped out on a tags where I had some background, with reference materials such as the Java Language Specification open in other windows.

Comment: @AwalGarg you need 75 reputation.  That consists of answering 3 questions good enough that one person thought they where acceptable (30) -- not accepted, just acceptable -- and asking 9 questions of similar quality (45), or some similar combination.  It isn't instant, but it shouldn't take that long.

Comment: @Yakk \@PatriciaShanahan Probably a lot more effort than just opening a new question. Why not suggest a policy change which exempts such questions from being closed?

Comment: On a second thought, actually, users just blindly vote as dupes, even experienced users; As I personally experience it in [this example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238069#comment780330_238069) [(later reopened by a more intelligent person)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238069#comment780350_238069) (and several other posts on [SuperUser]). The present policy _does_ exempt such questions, as rightly stated by user l4mpi in [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269631#comment84281_269631). But it is not intelligently enforced.

Comment: You could also add a line to the beginning of the new question akin to: This question is related to [This] question, but involves newer version of the software so ***should not be considered a duplicate***. Sure some people are still going to flag but I think it will be significantly less likely that it will actually be closed.