# A more consistent way of dealing with versions

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, versions

While versions are immensely important in programming, Stack Overflow has no mechanics built into it to actually deal with versions. This is quite contrary to (for example) every issue tracker for any sizable software, where you usually can't even post an issue without referencing the specific version of the software.

On SO people often tend to ask questions without referencing a version.

This leads to a couple of problems:

- Old questions often have accepted answers with a high score that don't work anymore.
- It is not clear whether a certain answer fits for the current version or not, because the answer does not show what version it was written for. The only indication is the date it was posted. Then again, depending on the topic, a question from 2012 might work just fine - or break your setup.
- Asking for an update (see [Ask for update to answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269631/ask-for-update-to-answers)) is not straight forward. In the referenced meta questions people suggested to either leave a comment and a bounty (which costs precious reputation) or re-ask the question for a different version, but questions like that tend to be closed as duplicates.

The current system allows a few different ways to handle that, but none are good.

The simplest way is to reference the version you are writing about in a question or answer. The problem here is that people just won't do it unless forced. And if you put this as a requirement into the rules, a lot of people will stumble over that because they forget. It would also increase the review queue length.

Another way that is implemented right now is version specific tags. A few topics already have that (e.g. [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) and [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x)), but it's usually not very granular and rightly so, because having a tag for every version of every framework would just be a terrible mess. Tags aren't designed for this kind of granularity.

I don't have a solid solution, hence the discussion tag and not a feature-request.

Do you think this is a valid problem? Do you have a possible solution?

Addendum:

**For who is this a problem?**

I think the current situation hinders the "repository of knowledge" aspect of SO. An answer on SO should not only help the person who asked the question, but also other people who have the same problem.
But if a version change changes the correct answer, thus rendering an older answer unhelpful, it would be better for a person stumbling upon that question/answer if that question had never been asked before. Because now they probably waste some time trying to get an outdated solution to work and after that it is a lot more difficult to ask for an updated answer, because they run a high risk to get their question closed as a duplicate, even though the old question does not solve their current problem.

I have been in this situation quite a few times so far.

Another problem that I observed specifically with Python questions is that the question is not tagged with a version tag, and then people write answers for all sorts of versions, often not mentioning for what version of Python their answer works. So someone who does not already know the answer might have to try multiple possible solutions just to figure ot which one is actually for their version of Python or of a library they are using.

**Aren't Version Tags the solution?**

I am not so sure. Currently, they are optional and thus are often not used. They are not much more of a solution to the problem than just writing the version your question/answer relates to into the text of the question/answer. I feel that the solution should be something mandatory that a asker/answerer is forced to fill in.

**There are also old answers that work on newer versions**

I am not sure what the point is here. There are also Java questions that might help a Python programmier, e.g. if they are both using the same cross-language library. Still I believe that categorising questions by language is useful.

Nothing stops someone from trying a solution for an older question. But, for example, if there is an answer for Java 7, one for Java 8 and one for Java 9 and I am using Java 10, then at least I know which one to try first.

Comment: For who is this a problem you think? Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374847/is-there-a-standard-we-can-point-to-for-versioning-tags (one among many)

Comment: It is not that we haven't [discussed this before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=version+tags+is%3Aq+answers%3A1+-%5Bbug%5D+-%5Bstatus-*%5D)

Comment: There are also a lot of old questions that have accepted answers with a high score that still work for newer (and older) versions.

Comment: I added answers to the comments into the question.

Comment: See also: [Should users be encouraged to include version numbers of libraries in their questions and answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358490/215552), [How to handle questions about outdated technologies?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280359/215552), [Mark questions or answers as out of date?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252520/215552),

Answer (score -5):

I think some kind of mandatory versioning of the questions and answers would be good. Just add another field when posting the question or answer that contains the version this post was written for.

That way people answering the question know what version the answer should be for, and also people looking for answers should get a quick overview of which answer will most likely fit their setup.

Couple this with a "Re-ask for a different version" feature, which just bumps the question and adds some kind of header above the question that says "This question has been re-asked for the following versions". That way there is no need to post a new question with the same content but just a different version number.